# Change the value of a key inside stdClass::__set_state(array(

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following returned array (*results from a `var_export()`*)

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'term_id' => 145,
     'name' => 'testing',
     'slug' => 'testing',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 145,
     'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
     'description' => '',
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 2,
     'filter' => 'raw',
  )),
)
```

I need to change the value of `$output[0]->count` to a new value. I can unset the key/value pair successfully with `unset($output[0]->count)`, but I just can't seem to set a new key/value pair.

I have tried using

```
$count['count'] = count( $list_term );
$result = array_merge_recursive($output, $count);
```

but then I get the following output

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'term_id' => 145,
     'name' => 'testing',
     'slug' => 'testing',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 145,
     'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
     'description' => '',
     'parent' => 0,
     'filter' => 'raw',
  )),
  'count' => 5,
)
```

If I try with

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($output[0], $count);
```

I get the following error

> WARNING Error: [2] array_merge_recursive(): Argument #1 is not an array

Any suggestions on how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast your object to an array

```
$result = array_merge_recursive((array)$output[0], $count);
```